# How to create a List<Object> with fields String and Map<String, Set<String>> from another List<Object2>

Tags: java, list, for-loop, set, java-stream

Class `Object2` has standard getters and has `String` fields `folder`, `file`, and `version`.
It is named `SourceInfo`

`List<SourceInfo> source` contains the three fields mentioned above.

My goal is to create a `List<Info>` from `List<SourceInfo>`.

The class of the new `List` is `Info`, shown below.

```
    public class Info {
      private final String folder;
      private final Map<String, Set<String>> file;
    
      public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
      }
    
      public static Builder builder(Info info) {
        return new Builder(info);
      }
    
      private Info(Builder builder) {
        this.folder = builder.folder;
        this.file = builder.file;
      }
    
      public String getFolder() {
        return folder;
      }
    
      public Map<String, Set<String>> getFile() {
        return file;
      }
    
      // autogenerated toString, hashCode, and equals
    
      public static class Builder {
        private String folder;
        private Map<String, Set<String>> file;
    
        private Builder() {}
    
        private Builder(Info info) {
          this.folder = info.folder;
          this.file = info.file;
        }
    
        public Builder with(Consumer<Builder> consumer) {
          consumer.accept(this);
          return this;
        }
    
        public Builder withFolder(String folder) {
          this.folder = folder;
          return this;
        }
    
        public Builder withFile(Map<String, Set<String>> file) {
          this.file = file;
          return this;
        }
    
        public Info build() {
          return new Info(this);
        }
      }
```

What I've tried so far is to create a set inside the builder pattern.

```
    List<SourceInfo> source;
    
    // error: gc overhead limit exceeded 

    List<Info> infoList = source.stream()
            .map(e -> Info.builder()
                .withFolder(e.getFolder())
                .withFile(source.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SourceInfo::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(SourceInfo::getVersion, Collectors.toSet()))))
                .build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = source.stream()
        .collect(Collectors
            .groupingBy(SourceInfo::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(SourceInfo::getVersion, Collectors.toSet())));
    
    List<Info> info = source.stream()
        .map(e -> Info.builder()
            .withFolder(e.getFolder())
            .withFile(map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue)))
            .build())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Desired output. The below syntax may be off.

```
// [String, Map<String, Set<String>>]

Info [folder, [key=file [value=version]]]
...
```

I'm new to Java, any help is appreciated.

I would like to understand how to do this using java8 and for loops.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First collect to a `Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>` then map it to a `List<Info>` using `Collectors#collectingAndThen` with `Collectors#groupingBy`

```java
List<Info> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Object2::getFolder,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                Object2::getFile,
                                Collectors.mapping(
                                        Object2::getVersion,
                                        Collectors.toSet()
                                )
                        )
                ),
                map -> map.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .map(entry -> new Info.Builder()
                                              .withFolder(entry.getKey())
                                              .withFile(entry.getValue())
                                              .build()
                        )
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ));
```

Comment: This doesn't create `Info` objects with `String` `folder` or `Map<String, Set<String>>` `file`, the andThen of `Collectors#collectingAndThen` forces the creation of a new constructor to run which returns null for `folder`, `file`. Looking for a way to build `Info` without new fields.

Comment: Info does not compile unfortunately, can you fix that first? Then I'll check.

Comment: Yes, it should compile now. Thanks

Comment: @zzzhw3137 I modified :) can you check if it's ok?